# Boundary conditions on wave equation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, boundary-conditions, string

[image: wave equation question]

I am having trouble understanding the boundary conditions.

From the solutions, the first is that $D_1(0, t) = D_2(0, t)$ because the rope can't break at the junction.

The second is that $\dfrac{\partial D_1}{\partial x} D_1(0, t) = \dfrac{\partial D_2}{\partial x}(0, t)$. How can I interpret this physically? I'm not quite sure how to think about $\partial D /\partial x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second condition is saying that there is no discontinuity in the *slope* of the rope at the junction.  In other words, there is no "kink" in the rope.

Imagine if this assumption were to fail in the following way:
$$
  \frac{\partial D_1}{\partial x}(0,t) = -1, \qquad \frac{\partial D_2}{\partial x}(0,t) = 1
$$
Then near the origin, the rope would look like the function $f(x) = |x|$ does at the origin; there would be a "triangular kink" in the rope facing upward.

**Addendum.  Why can't there be a kink?** In response to Nathaniel's response, here's why there can't be a kink.  We argue by way of contradiction.

Suppose that there were a kink, and consider a small mass element centered on the junction.  In the presence of a kink, the tensions on either side of the junction would point in different directions, and there would therefore be a net force on the small mass element.  Now consider taking the size of that mass element to zero.  There will be a net force on the mass element as we take the limit of its size to zero, but its mass will vanish, which yields a contradiction to Newton's second law.

Comment: I guess the question is, why isn't that allowed? Since there *is* a discontinuity in the linear density of the rope, it's not immediately intuitively obvious that a kink can't develop at that point. (I think it can be derived from energy conservation, though.)

Comment: @Nathaniel I made an addition to address your points.