# What equation can be used to solve an ideal string/membrane in a non-vacuum medium?

Tags: waves, eigenvalue, vibrations, interactions

I'm interested in the eigenmodes of the membrane for various mediums, such as vacuum, air, water, etc., which impose a damping effect on the membrane.

This cannot be done by [merely changing the value](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/95271/wave-equation-in-varying-mediums) for the wave propagation speed, c, because this value belongs to the string/membrane itself, and not to the medium around it.

Can the influence of medium be incorporated in the wave equation for vibrating string/membrane?

Comment: I don't get it. You probably mean that the 'boundary' is not sharp, but extended over a small region. Then, the only change as per Josh's answer in the linked post would be to have two sets of boundary condition matchings, one for the wave going from medium 1 to 2 and another for the medium 2 to 3. If the medium supports wave propagation, good. Otherwise, you get an evanescent wave in medium 2, and its amplitude at the edge of medium 2 serves as the effective starting amplitude in medium 3. Why is this wrong?

Comment: In this case I don't have a wave moving in a medium, but a vibration (deflection) of string/membrane, which is governed by the wave equation, and to a certain extent, the medium is the string/membrane itself. What I meant by "medium" is what's around the string/membrane.

Comment: There are no "eigenstates of the membrane". There can only be eigenstates of the complete system (assuming that the system is sufficiently linear to allow for a linear approximation). As a result you will have to know what the propagation velocity in the medium is and what shape the medium has... which brings us to concert hall acoustics, which is a very tough nut, indeed.